# jQuery mousedown + mouseleave

Tags: jquery

i'm a begginer currently building a simple jQuery script where i'd like my action to happen when I drag out of its bounds. So i was thinking on detecting a mousedown and inside its function have a mouseleave.

But what happens is not what i'm expecting since everytime i pass my mouse over it - no need to click, the event gets triggered.

Here's the code i've put toghether.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".box").mousedown(function() {
     $(".box").mouseleave(function() {
       alert("Hello world!");
     });
   });
 });
```

Help much appreciated, thanx!

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(".box").mousedown(function() {
     alert('mousedown');
     $(this).addClass('imclicked');
   }).mouseleave(function() {
       if($(this).hasClass('imclicked')) {
         alert("Hello world!");
         $(this).removeClass('imclicked');
       }
   });;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".box").mousedown(function() {
        $('.box').addClass('clicked');
    });
    $(".box").mouseleave(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
            $(this).removeClass('clicked');
            alert("Hello world!");
        }
     });
 });
```

The `mouseleave` will only continue if `.box` has the CSS class `clicked`, and will then remove the class, stopping the `mouseleave` from being triggered again.

Comment: (Don't forget to accept an answer if you feel your problem has been adequately solved)

Comment: i added a new line cause i found that clicking and moving out, also caused the action to happen:


 $(".box").mouseup(function() {
  $('.box').removeClass('clicked');
 });

Comment: Good call. That's a sensible addition to make :)

Answer (score 0):

Just unbind the event after it's triggered:

```
$(".box").mousedown(function() {
    $(this).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).unbind('mouseleave');
        alert("Hello world!");
    })
})
```